# `var` in css not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have two variables for horizontal and vertical alignment say `xPos` and `yPos` and it will assign the value as 0 for it in css like this:

```
var xPos="left",
    yPos="bottom";
    
$(".applyCss").css({
    "width":"200px",
    "height":"200px",
    "position":"absolute",
    "background-color":"#E0E0E0",
    [xPos]:0,
    [yPos]:0
});
```

This logic is working fine except in IE. It shows

```
Expected identifier, string or number
```

I referred many questions in StackOverflow, and i got the answer as "Internet Explorer have troubles with trailing commas in objects and arrays". But i didn't get any solution for this problem

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/ttmcr1s3/1/)

(Note: I got a workaround for this problem, but i want to know a solution for this method)

Comment: The syntax `{[p]: k}` is ES2015. What version of IE are you using? Note that's the same as assigning the object to a variable and using bracket notation afterwards, like `var o={}; o[p]=k`, that's supported in all browsers.

Comment: [IE doesn't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility) computed property names

Comment: @elclanrs My IE version is 10

Comment: That's too old, if anything IE Edge might support it, otherwise go with the ES5 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

That object literal bracket syntax is new to ES6 (also known as ES2015). It'll work in modern browsers like Firefox, Chrome, and Edge, but IE barely achieves ES5 compliance.

Either use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) for browser compatibility, or use the old trusty syntax:

```
var xPos="left",
    yPos="bottom";

var myStyles = {
    "width":"200px",
    "height":"200px",
    "position":"absolute",
    "background-color":"#E0E0E0",
};
myStyles[xPos] = 0;
myStyles[yPos] = 0;
$(".applyCss").css(myStyles);
```